# Android Gradle Nexus Plugin didn't find task sourcesJar

Tags: android, gradle, nexus

I use plugin https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin for upload builds to our server. Gradle Sync executed without erros but I didn't find anything new Gradle Tasks (sourcesJar, javadocJar, etc). Also I didn't have "archive" directory in Gradle Project tab.

My settings in build.gradle

```
nexus {
   sign = true
   repositoryUrl = 'https://...'
   snapshotRepositoryUrl = 'https://...'
}
```

Comment: Run with --info or --debug so see more information that might help debug the issue

Comment: The tasks added by the plugin could be grouped under a category. Have you looked under all the categories? You can also try `gradle tasks --all` from the commandline.

Comment: Yes, I looked at all categories and didn't find it.

Comment: I mean didn't find new tasks